# VBA get start date from week number of the year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to retrieve the date of the first day of a week (week starts on Monday) knowing the year and the number of the week. (52 weeks in 1 year)

```
Dim nYear As Integer, _
    nWeek, As Integer
    startDate As Date

    nYear = 2018
    nWeek= 1


'startDate = ?
```

Expected result : `01/01/2018`

Is there a simple & dynamic way to do so?

Thank you

Comment: What's your input, what's your expected output? Can you give an example?

Comment: i just updated the question!

Comment: Week 1 is the first week of the trimester? how are you count the week, it is the first full week (sunday-saturday, monday-sunday) or if the first day of the trimester is a friday then every friday is the begining of the week?

Comment: It isn't possible to determine the start date of any week in a trimester without knowing the start date of the trimester itself.

Comment: How long is a trimester? if it's a third of a year it's neither a whole number of days or weeks.

Comment: thank you all, i just updated my question

Comment: The first day of the first week of 2019 is 31/12/2018

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim nTrimester As Integer, _
    nYear As Integer, _
    nWeek As Integer, _
    wd As Integer, _
    startDate As Date, _
    inputDate As Date

nYear = 2019
nWeek = 1    

inputDate = DateSerial(nYear, 1, 1)
inputDate = DateAdd("ww", nWeek - 1, inputDate)
wd = Weekday(inputDate, vbMonday)   

startDate = DateAdd("d", 1 - wd, inputDate)
```

Edit:
The answer above consider the first week of the year the week of the first day of the year. According to ISO 8601, the first week of the year is the one with the first Thursday of the year, so, it should be

```
Dim nTrimester As Integer, _
    nYear As Integer, _
    nWeek As Integer, _
    wd As Integer, _
    startDate As Date, _
    inputDate As Date

nYear = 2021
nWeek = 1

inputDate = DateSerial(nYear, 1, 1)

If Weekday(inputDate, vbMonday) > 4 Then
    nWeek = nWeek + 1
End If
    
inputDate = DateAdd("ww", nWeek - 1, inputDate)
wd = Weekday(inputDate, vbMonday)

startDate = DateAdd("d", 1 - wd, inputDate)
```

The differences of the two approaches is that for the first, the first day of the first week of 2021 is 2020-12-28, and for the second, it is 2021-01-04

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

```
startDate = DateAdd("ww", nWeek, DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1))
```

Thank you to everyone that wanted to help!

If you have something that works the same or better, feel free to add it

Comment: I tested your code for 2019 week 1 and it results in 08/01/2019, which is a Tuesday. Your sample code worked because 2018 started in a Monday.

Comment: right thank you for pointing it out, i don't know how to correct that bug

Comment: Check my answer, for the scenarios that you provided, it worked, including _The first day of the first week of 2019 is 31/12/2018_

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You must take into account the day of the week of the first day of the year.

```
    startDate = DateAdd("ww", IIF(WeekDay(DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1))>4, nWeek,nWeek-1), DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1))
```